# Add <meta/> tags dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta

I want to add `<meta/>` tags dynamically using javascript/Jquery.

```
<head>

</head> 
<body>
// From here I want to add <meta/> tags dynamically using javascript/Jquery    
// into <head> tag. 
</body>
```

So my question is that "is it possible to do so?".

And if yes then How?

Comment: `is it possible to do so` yes, it is possible. that is jquery 101. Please share what you have tried.

Comment: instead of typing such a big question here why not you tried it on [google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=add+meta+tag+dynamically+jquery) ???

Comment: Using scripts to add tags are not advisable as some search engine crawlers will consider only the html and ignore js.

Comment: You can, but there's no point in doing so.

Comment: Just like you would add any other HTML element to any other DOM element. That question is so elementary that you could get a grasp of it within 2seconds googling

Answer (score 1):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz5e56dg/)

```
$('head').append('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">');
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery append you can achieve the desired result.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrwwawny/)

```
$(function() {
  $('head').append('<meta tag="test"/>');
});
```